# Android Studio 2.2.1 Jumbled text in code editor

Tags: android, android-studio-2.2

The jumbled code is just in the code editor under the tab for the MainActivity.java file The text looks like this:pro t ec ed Vo i d. If I copy and paste here it turns out normal. I think it may be an encoding issue but the language is English(My Language). I uninstalled and downloaded the IDE and re-installed it and still have the problem. The default app builds fine and I get an apk file which I have side-loaded to my phone, installed it, and I get "Hello World" so it seems the jumbled text has no effect on the final result. If I cut and paste from notepad the pasted text is also jumbled.

I was going to post it in Google's AS forum but as I am a beginner to AS I was directed here. Sure hope you can help me!
Paul

Answer (score 1):

In Android Studio:
File -> Other Settings -> Default Settings, then find "File Encodings", change Project Encoding to UTF-8.